# Android AVD run fails and HAXM install fails after SDK tools update

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools, haxm

I just updated my android SDK tools to 26.1.1 as it was showing "Updates available", after that my AVD couldn't start, it gave following HAXM related error, although the HAXM was already installed and was working fine before the SDK tools update.

[image]

So I uninstalled the HAXM and tried to install it again, but the installation failed giving the following error :

[image]

[image]

Then I installed the HAXM separately, after downloading the latest ver from git repo (https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.5.4)
It got installed properly, but still the AVD is failing with same error.

[image]

Following the current state of my SDK Tools :

[image]

I am working on Win 10 Pro, x86_64, 4GB RAM, Core i7-3517U

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, you need to go to SDK manager and update Android Emulator to version 29.3.2
then try to install en SDK manager Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)
and thats it.
all working fine again.

[Android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxwmU.png)

Comment: Thanks, But I resolved this by uninstalling the existing Android Studio, and installed the 3.6 Beta version, and the latest VC_redistributable. It works now. And I will not try anything else until something breaks again. (Installing unstable updates makes things worse)